# Redoing after an accidental change in Vim

Tags: vim, undo

Let's say I make 3 changes, C1, C2, and C3.

Then I undo X3. Then I redo X3. I'm back where I started.

Then I undo X3 again, but then I accidentally type `ifoo<Esc>`.  What can I now do to recover change #3?

Answer (score 11):

Vim is special in that it not just stores a linear history of edits (and undo), but actually all branches! You can use the `g-` and `g+` commands to move through them, and the `:earlier` command to move to text states by count, seconds, minutes, etc. See `:help undo-branches` and `:help usr_32.txt` for details.

#### Plugin recommendations

Because that kind of navigation is still mentally taxing (and one doesn't want to get lost in a potentially huge undo tree!), the [undotree.vim - Display your undo history in a graph](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177) and [Gundo - Visualize your undo tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) plugins provide a much better visualization, including diffs to see what changed in each state.

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know about undotree.  I was going to install Python just because Gundo needs it, but this saves me from doing that.

Comment: Yes, Gundo was first and seems to be more popular, but I also use undotree; I also like that its tree is more compact.

Answer (score 5):

Given that sequence, you should be able to type `g-` (<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>) one time to get back to change 3.  You might want to open another instance of Vim and test it to verify it does what you want.

Type `:h undo-branches` for more information.